# How can I make images fill 100% of a div if "they don't fit"

Tags: javascript, css

I have multiple images (50x50), my site width is 980 px

I want to fill one row with images, without any gap. But without any CSS/JS/help from you, the 20th images ends up on the second row.

How can I show 40% of the 20th images?

Comment: You want to do it without my help? Impossible!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution by myself.

Use CSS to display a shorter width:

```
<?php
    $img = "";
    $width = 50;
    for($i=0;$i<20;$i++) {
        if($i == 19) {
            $width = 30;
        }
?>
<img src="<?=$img;>" style="width: <?=$width;?>px; height:50px;" />
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: But you said 'without any CSS/JS/help'

Answer (score 4):

On your `container` div:

```
#container{
    overflow:hidden; /* Hide the overflow */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img:nth-child(20n) { width:30px; }
```